# How to update or reload other controller in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application in Angularjs. I am finding hard to reload controller. I am using ui-routing. I have created plunker at `//plnkr.co/edit/ozojBNobd44SqGeEVvvN?p=preview.` I have login tab. On clicking on login my login.html will be rendered. After user entering username and password when the user clicks on Login I want to reload the scotchController inside app.js file.

I tried many methods including $state.go() and transition. None of them worked out. May i get some help to fix this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more why you need to reload the controller ? 
After Login; you have to redirect the user to a specific page where your controller is a dependency; like that; your controller will be loaded ONLY after authentication

Comment: Thanks. I will be having userprofile tab in index.html that contains image. After succesfull login i will set cookie. at the time of setting cookie i want to reload the scotchController controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using this ?

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="loginCtrl">  

<button ng-click="doLogin();"></button> 

</div> 


<script> 
var app = angular.module('myApp', []); 
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) { 
function doLogin($scope) { 
// call service and call this on success 
var arrayData = [1,2,3]; 
$rootScope.$emit('someEvent', arrayData); 
} 

}); 
app.controller('scotchController', function($scope, $rootScope,$state) { 
$rootScope.$on('someEvent', function(event, data) { 
console.log(data);  
$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true}); 
});  
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you want to reload controller after login? it already initializes after loading view.

Comment: After login some value i will be set in cookie. and in scotchController controller i want to set some image like if(cookie exists set some image)

Comment: You can do that when controller initializes, i.e. redirecting login to scotch page. It loads automatically

Comment: Please try to understand. initally scotchController loads then after login only i will set cookie. Same time i want to trigger scotchController.

Comment: Then you can just reload that variable then, Why do you need to reload whole controller?

Comment: I agree but variable will change but scotchController will not execute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146259/discussion-between-niranjan-godbole-and-sangwin-gawande).

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: Sorry i started getting error. $state is not defined
    at App.js:247
    at ChildScope.$emit (angular.js:16127)
    at LoginSuccess (LoginController.js:59)
    at LoginController.js:30

Comment: Add $state in providers, like I did in above code. app.controller('scotchController', function($scope, $rootScope,$state)